# GitFlow Unity3D and Branch specific Application Data

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, branch, git-flow, build-settings

I'm currently using GitFlow as my branching model for a Unity3D application. The master branch is my production branch and the development branch is self-evident. 
Both of these branches have corresponding cloud build applications.

When code is pushed to develop, the development build gets created and distributed automatically. When code is merged to master after a release, a release build is automatically created, which I can then download and push to apple.

Build settings is a big file and there are only certain fields I wish to have build specific. My current strategy, which I don't like, is to create a release branch with git-flow, commit in changes specific to the release and finish the release. (which merges all these changes into master and back into development). This leads to an automatic development build (which I currently manually stop) with the incorrect build settings.

You can see why this is not desirable: Not only to I get a broken development build, but I have to adjust build settings each time I want to release which is quite often and prone to user error.

Anyone have a better strategy or suggestion on a better way to go about this?

Comment: Interesting. We have disabled automatic builds on the master since this is our main branch and gets a lot of commits. Every time we want a build we need to start it manually. We also have a release branch that builds automatically when something gets pushed. This branch is setup with correct credentials to be able to create an ipa ready for Application Loader. Works fine most of the times, if the build number is correctly changed. Hope you get a good answer on this one since I would like to up our flow as well.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Mattias. I just stumbled upon the: Pre-Export Method Name. Which allows you to specify to cloud-build a public static method to run prior to the build process. I will probably try to leverage this to configure the settings appropriately for submission builds. I'll update with my experiments.

Comment: We put our releases in a production/master branch, and periodically merge master into that branch.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a better strategy for this:

Unity cloud build allows you to add a pre-export method (and post export). Things to note, this method must be a public static method and it must be within a folder named 'editor'.

[image: pre-export method]

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
using UnityEditor;

public static class BuildSettings
{
    public static void ProductionPreBuild()
    {
        PlayerSettings.bundleIdentifier = "com.company.production";
    }

    public static void DevelopmentPreBuild()
    {
        PlayerSettings.bundleIdentifier = "com.company.development";
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you handle version and build numbers?

Comment: Currently, I'm still doing it manually. The increment is my last step on my release branch and that gets merged into both development and master at the time of release.